# How to toggle setInterval on click javascript

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to be able to toggle setInterval on click.

Here is my code that start the interval:

```
var clock = document.querySelector('#hexTime');
var hexClock = document.querySelector('#hexClock');
function run() {
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = (time.getHours() % 12).toString();
  var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
  if(hours.length < 2) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
  if(minutes.length < 2) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if(seconds.length < 2) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
  var hexStr = '#' + hours + minutes + seconds;

  clock.textContent = clockStr;
  hexClock.textContent = hexStr;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexStr;
}

run();

setInterval(run, 1000);
```

How can I acheive that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

First, add an element (preferably a button) that will listen for the click, give it an ID like:

```
<button id="myToggleButton">CLICK ME</button>
```

Then add an event listener for that element and set or clear interval when it's clicked like:

```
var clock = document.querySelector('#hexTime');
var hexClock = document.querySelector('#hexClock');
function run() {
  var time = new Date();
  var hours = (time.getHours() % 12).toString();
  var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
  var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
  if(hours.length < 2) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
  if(minutes.length < 2) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }
  if(seconds.length < 2) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }
  var clockStr = hours + ' : ' + minutes + ' : ' + seconds;
  var hexStr = '#' + hours + minutes + seconds;

  clock.textContent = clockStr;
  hexClock.textContent = hexStr;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexStr;
}


var myButton = document.querySelector('#myToggleButton');

// this will hold the information about the interval
var myInterval = null;

// the event listener for the click event
myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(myInterval){ // if we have an interval (myInterval != null)
    clearInterval(myInterval); // clear it
    myInterval = null; // make it null again
  }
  else{ // if we don't have an interval (myIntervall == null)
    myInterval = setInterval(run, 1000); // start one
  }
});

// if you don't want the interval to start by default then remove the next line
myInterval = setInterval(run, 1000);
```